# How to type this symbol in LaTeX (commonly used to denote a sector)?

Tags: formatting, typography, letters

I'm sorry to ask such an elementary question. I am wanting to know how to type the following symbol in LaTeX, it is written with a subscript 'l' in the image below,

[image]

I feel quite illiterate because I don't even know how to read this symbol. I have tried typing the (English) alphabet in various font styles but nothing matched.

Many thanks

Comment: `\usepackage{mathscr}` and `\mathscr{S}`.

Comment: Apologies @Moriambar I did not see the previous thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ mathrsfs }
\begin{document}
    \[
    \mathscr{S}_l
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Wow.. I did try this (as I say, I tried the whole alphabet in various fonts)... I don't know how I missed it

Comment: @analytic You're welcome! Detexify of the duplicate question is very useful!